# Is there a way to query the time when data was last modified (add/edit/delete) in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to periodically aggregate a column in a table containing large number of rows. I save the aggregate results, so i don't want to perform the expensive aggregate operation unless any data in the table is modified.

I do have a "last modified" column in the table but querying `MAX(lastModifiedColumn)` seems expensive on a million row table.

I'm also not allowed to use triggers.

Any performance friendly solution for this?

Comment: "...querying MAX(lastModifiedColumn) seems expensive on a million rows..." -- if you have an index on that column, the query is instantaneous, even if it's a billion rows.

Comment: If you have an index on lastModifiedColumn then using MAX really isn't a big deal. Instead of assuming it will be too slow you should try it and see.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand indexing lastModifiedColumn will help, but I might not be able to create index on the table.

Comment: Don't make weird decisions based on your possible ability to do something. YOU should know if you can create an index or not....or perhaps there already is one. If you are not allowed to add an index, then speak to your DBA and explain **why** it needs an index. Anything other than indexing here is the wrong way to solve this.

Comment: Even if I was able to create index, wouldn't that involve performance penalty while adding/deleting rows in the table.

Comment: @RohanRaja As opposed to the penalty you now incur trying to do your calculation? Nothing is free; everything has a cost. So the question here is "will the cost of maintaining the index during typical DML operations exceed the benefit to this query?". I'll guess no but the only way to know for certain is to test it. And note that a million rows is not generally considered a big table these days. Don't try to solve a problem you do not yet have.